# How to create env file in GCP?

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to create `.env` in GCP cloud build.
The `cloudbuild.yaml` file

```
steps:
- name: 'python:3.8'
  entrypoint: python3
  args: ['-m', 'pip', 'install', '-t', '.', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
- name: 'python:3.8'
  entrypoint: python3
  args: ['touch', '.env']
  env:
    - 'DATABASE_HOST=$$DB_HOST'
    - 'DATABASE_USER=$$DB_USER'
    - 'DATABASE_PASSWORD=$$DB_PASS'
    - 'DATABASE_NAME=$$DB_NAME'
    - 'FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=$$FIRE_CRED'
- name: 'python:3.8'
  entrypoint: python3
  args: ['./manage.py', 'collectstatic', '--noinput']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

I've tried with several ways to do that but it's not yet solved.
Created Substitution variable in GCP Trigger that I used in env.

The problem is

```
- name: 'python:3.8'
  entrypoint: python3
  args: ['touch', '.env']
  env:
    - 'DATABASE_HOST=$$DB_HOST'
    - 'DATABASE_USER=$$DB_USER'
    - 'DATABASE_PASSWORD=$$DB_PASS'
    - 'DATABASE_NAME=$$DB_NAME'
    - 'FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=$$FIRE_CRED'
```

This portion of the code.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

I have used `args: ['./create-env.py']` instead of    `args: ['touch', '.env']` and write the environment file to `.env`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, let's start on correct basis. In Cloud Build, each step run a container. This runtime is based on an image (the `name`) and several parameters (`entrypoint`, `args`, `env`,...)

`env` allow you to define environment variable in the runtime environment, for example

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: "echo"
    args: ["$$ENV_VAR"]
    env:
      - 'ENV_VAR=WORKS'
```

will display `WORKS`. The entry point `echo` has in argument `$$ENV_VAR`. The value of this environment variable, in the runtime environment is equals to `WORKS`.

*Note the double $. It's a special mention to indicate to not search in the substitution variables (single $) but to search in the runtime environment variables*

A final word: from 1 step to another one, the runtime is destroyed and recreated. only the `/workspace` directory is kept. All other files and env vars are destroyed.

---

At the end, I'm not sure of what you want to achieve:

- Create a `.env` file from your env vars? I don't understand the `entrypoint` and the `args` of your step
- Load env vars from a `.env` file? if so, it's useless because the context is offloaded between each step.

So, if you need more guidance, explain the ultimate target of your code, I will update this answer accordingly.

Comment: It is a very good clarification and explanation Guillaume.

Comment: It's a great explanation, and I mange to solve the problem to create a python script for writing the env file. Thank you so much